# Can't run rmarkdown on Amazon Linux 2 due to Pandoc not available

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, r-markdown, pandoc, amazon-linux

I'm using Amazon Linux 2, t2.large.

I understand the reason why I could not run `rmarkdown::run()` is because pandoc was not installed/configured correctly. After Googling for hours, I tried `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")` (empty result); I tried [rmarkdown not working due to pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215191/rmarkdown-not-working-due-to-pandoc), but `apt-get` was not found; I tried downloading pandoc and move `pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc` to `/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc`according to https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/articles/pandoc.html, but the error about pandoc not available remained; I tried to follow this page https://pandoc.org/installing.html#linux, but I was stuck at the first step after downloading pandoc under the Linux section, the error was `command dpkg not found`.

It is difficult because I'm not sure how to get common commands such as `apt-get` to work in Amazon Linux and many of the packages I need do not exist in `amazon-linux-extras` or `yum install`.

To set up, I ran the code below:

```
sudo su

amazon-linux-extras install R3.4

wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-1.0.153-x86_64.rpm --no-check-certificate
yum install -y --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-1.0.153-x86_64.rpm
rm rstudio-server-rhel-1.0.153-x86_64.rpm
R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
R -e "install.packages('rmarkdown', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

To run the .rmd file:

```
R
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
rmarkdown::run(file = "placeholder.Rmd", shiny_args = list(host = 'my.ip', port = X, launch.browser = F))
```

> pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found

Please note I can run Shiny example using this:

```
runExample('01_hello', host = 'my.ip', port = X, launch.browser = F)
```

Comment: RStudio server version 1.0.x is quite old. How about installing a more current version? This will also incluse a more recent version of `pandoc`.

Comment: Please comment if you ended up finding a solution to this

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux 2 is not Debian-based. It is closer to a CentOS flavor. As such, it uses `yum` and not `apt-get`.

To install `pandoc`, you may try:

```bash
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum -y install pandoc --enablerepo=epel
```

Credit: this [comment here](https://gist.github.com/backroot/3898b897a21987a5314051b6818411f3?permalink_comment_id=3626060#gistcomment-3626060) on a GitHub repo.

Comment: For me this installs pandoc 1.12, I need atleast 2.06